# How to add SIMD-related compiler flags in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sse, flags, simd, compiler-flags

I found this list of flags:

http://www.ncsa.illinois.edu/UserInfo/Resources/Software/Intel/Compilers/10.0/main_for/mergedProjects/optaps_for/common/optaps_dsp_targ.htm

and I'd like to try and add some of them to my project. I can't seem to find the way to do it on a visual studio 2010 platform :(

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [/arch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd.aspx) flag in Visual Studio allows you to specify the target processor architecture, and includes support for SSE2, amongst others. This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289168%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#optimization_topic3) describes how the flag works in the context of SIMD/SSE2.

Visual Studio also supports [explicit usage of SSE2 instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0dh78ez%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) via [compiler intrinsics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26td21ds%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).