# odeint memory usage and execution time

Tags: c++, numerical-methods

I've noticed that odeint uses very little memory when compared to my implementation of the RK4 algorithm or Mathematica. For the same step size, odeint uses about 3.11GB while my program uses 7GB and with Mathematica, I have to manually increase the pagefile size to 40GB or else it runs out of memory. (Edit: **CPU usage is only 18%**)

I am curious on how this is possible because when I save the results, the data file is almost the same size in all three cases.

However, when it comes to execution time, odeint seems an order of magnitude slower than either my program or Mathematica. Is this tradeoff normal? I do things the **super noob** way.

**Edit:2**
** Step Size vs Execution Time **

- 0.0005=2:55.59 ~ 24.44hrs for 500 steps
- 0.001=1:29.14 ~ 12.5hrs for 500 steps
- 0.005= 0:17.19~ 2.5hrs for 500 steps.
- 0.01= 8.34 ~ 1hr10min for 500 steps

For example:

```
void Classical(vector<vector<double> >& u1,vector<vector<double> >& u2,vector<vector<double> >& phi1,vector<double>& delta,vector<vector<double> >& theta,vector<vector<double> >& phi2, vector<double>& Gamma,vector<double>& z,double h,double u10,double u20,double theta_initial){

for(int i=0;i<delta.size();++i){ 

        double v1=u10;
        double v2=u20;
        double ph1=0.0;
        double ph2=0.0;
        double angle=delta[i]; //OK



    u1.push_back ( vector<double>() );
    u2.push_back ( vector<double>() );
    phi1.push_back ( vector<double>() );
    phi2.push_back ( vector<double>() );
    theta.push_back ( vector<double>() );

        for(int j=0;j<z.size();++j){



            double k1=0.0; double k2=0.0;double k3=0.0;double k4=0.0;
            double L1=0.0; double L2=0.0;double L3=0.0;double L4=0.0;
            double m1=0.0; double m2=0.0;double m3=0.0;double m4=0.0;
            double n1=0.0; double n2=0.0;double n3=0.0;double n4=0.0;                               


            k1=h*(v2*v2-1.0)*cos((angle));
            L1=h*( (2.0/(1.0-(v2*v2))) - (1.0/(v2*v2)) )*Gamma[i];
            m1=h*(1.0/(1.0-(v2*v2)))*Gamma[i];
            n1=h*(1.0/((v2*v2)))*Gamma[i];

            k2=h*((v2+k1/2)*(v2+k1/2)-1)*cos(((angle+L1/2)));
            L2=h*( (2.0/(1-((v2+k1/2)*(v2+k1/2)))) - (1/((v2+k1/2)*(v2+k1/2))) )*Gamma[i];
            m2=h*(1/(1-((v2+k1/2)*(v2+k1/2))))*Gamma[i];
            n2=h*(1/(((v2+k1/2)*(v2+k1/2))))*Gamma[i];

            k3=h*((v2+k2/2)*(v2+k2/2)-1)*cos(((angle+L2/2)));
            L3=h*( (2.0/(1-((v2+k2/2)*(v2+k2/2)))) - (1/((v2+k2/2)*(v2+k2/2))) )*Gamma[i];
            m3=h*(1/(1-((v2+k2/2)*(v2+k2/2))))*Gamma[i];
            n3=h*(1/(((v2+k2/2)*(v2+k2/2))))*Gamma[i];

            k4=h*((v2+k3)*(v2+k3)-1)*cos(((angle+L3)));
            L4=h*( (2.0/(1-((v2+k3)*(v2+k3)))) - (1/((v2+k3)*(v2+k3))) )*Gamma[i];
            m4=h*(1/(1-((v2+k3)*(v2+k3))))*Gamma[i];
            n4=h*(1/(((v2+k3)*(v2+k3))))*Gamma[i];


            v2=v2+(k1/6)+(k2/3)+(k3/3)+(k4/6); 
            angle=angle + (L1/6)+(L2/3)+(L3/3)+(L4/6);
            ph1=ph1+(m1/6)+(m2/3)+(m3/3)+(m4/6); 
            ph2=ph2+(n1/6)+(n2/3)+(n3/3)+(n4/6);

            v1=sqrt(1.0-(v2*v2));

            u1[i].push_back(v1);
            u2[i].push_back(v2);
            theta[i].push_back(angle);
            phi1[i].push_back(ph1);
            phi2[i].push_back(ph2);
        }


}
```

}

Comment: Just a tip, from the looks of it your program could benefit a __lot__ from parallelization, both in the form of threads and SSE.

Comment: How to do that? I am a complete noob, but willing to learn.

Comment: I don't have any experience with using threads for C++ scientific calculation, but using SSE optimalizations could be as simple as adding the apprioriate option for your compiler. What compiler are you using?

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2010. Compiler options are: {/ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"Debug\file_read.pch" /Fa"Debug\" /Fo"Debug\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue}

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890049/how-to-add-simd-related-compiler-flags-in-visual-studio-2010) for enabling SSE in VS2010. Just a word of notice, executables compiled for the SSE architecture don't work on processors that don't have SSE. Most modern processors do however.

Comment: I like how you bolded **super noob**.  It made me smile :)

Comment: @nightcracker; I found some more info here-->http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg663540, but not sure if it is applicable or not. Wug, it is easier/better to be upfront about such stuff so that those helping know what they are in for. ;) Added some info about CPU usage.

Comment: For those reading the above discussion of SSE with confusion, it seems to be a set of assembly/machine-code instructions for quick manipulation of single-precision floating values. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should compile your programs in release modus to enable compiler optimization. odeint uses lots of template code which is quite slow when compiled in debug modus. The performance will be increaced by orders of magnitude in release modus.

Comment: O.k. I am trying it now. It is taking about 5~6 hours to run a set of 20 coupled diff-eqs with a step size of 0.0005. I hope your suggestion will speed it up.

Comment: How long is you integration time?

Comment: For one iteration it is 2:55.59 in "Release" mode. This is not including load-up time for boost libraries. Step size=0.00050. I timed it with my stopwatch. So it should take 24.44hrs to run 500 iterations. Maybe I should break it up into 10 different Visual Studio instances and run them together. Quite an ugly way to do things.

Comment: What is you system size? I mean how many entries does you ODE vector have?

Comment: The ODE vector has 21 entries, i.e from x[0] to x[20].

Comment: What is the performance boost in release modus compared to your original performance?

Comment: I will get back to you on this, but for sure it is certainly less than an order of magnitude.

Comment: @headmyshoulder, how do you compile the odeint code in release modus? Is it a flag or define or something else?

Comment: If you use gcc compile with `-O3`. If you use Visual Studio there is a release mode or release profile which should be used.